# The mid-point rule as a function in matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

How would I go about creating a function in matlab which would calculate the following

$$M_c(f)=h \sum_{i=1}^N f(c_i)$$

where

$h=\frac{b-a}{N}, \\c_i=a+0.5(2i-1)h,\\ i=1,\ldots,N$

What I have tried so far is

```
function(M(f))= composite_midpoint(f)

h=(b-a)/N
for i=1:1:N
   c_i=a+0.5*(2i-1)*h
   M(f) = h*(sum + f)
end
```

Sorry about not inserting the matlab code directly, I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Updated the formatting, you can use four spaces in front of each line to show code.

Comment: What types of 'functions' are you expecting to be able to input for f?  Symbolic functions, or matlab functions?

Comment: It would be a function which is smooth enough for Taylor's theorem and one which it's integral can be calculated exactly.

Comment: Yes, but with matlab functions are either .m files or "symbolic" functions.  Its not going to work the way you have it written if you call it like "composite_midpoint(x^2)".  It doesn't know what x^2 means.

Comment: If I were to want the function to be x^2 how would I go about altering my code so that it worked for the midpoint rule?

Comment: I have included an example, you can replace f = c_i.^2 if you want your function to be the square function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run this outside the function:

```
a = 6; 
b = 4.234;
N = 10;
```

Then save this function to a file called compositemidpoint.m (in your current directory)

```
function M = compositemidpoint(a,b,N)
h = (b-a)/N
i = 1:N
c_i = a+0.5*(2*i-1)*h
f = log(c_i) + c_i.^2 % A sample function
M = h*sum(f);
```

Then call it by typing:

```
compositemidpoint(a,b,N)
```

Comment: It does not really make sens yet, but this is how i debugged your attempted code to not-crash.

Comment: Your code only sums the vector $f$ and multiplies it by $h$.  There is no midpoint rule occurring here - you have to create the vector $f$ by evaluating some function at the grid points $c_i$...

Comment: I have updated the answer to include an example function.

Comment: I tried running this but it wouldn't work. I've put in function out= compositemidpoint at the very begining of the function however it is still coming up with errors.

Comment: I have included some instructions on how to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, which is vectorized (for loops are bad in matlab).

```
function Mf=midpoint_rule(a,b,N,f)

h=(b-a)/N;
%ci are your evaluation points
ci=linspace(a+h/2,b-h/2,N-1);
%This evaluates the function f, which is another matlab function
y=f(ci);
%you can just add up the vector y and multiply by h
Mf=h*sum(y);

end
```

For example, you can save another .m file  Myfunction.m, that might look like:

```
function y=Myfunction(x)

%The dot means "pointwise"
y=x.^2

end
```

Then, in the main window, you would evaluate the integral by saying "midpoint_rule(1,2,100,@Myfunction)".   The "at" symbol tells matlab you'll be using a matlab function called "Myfunction".

Comment: If you only need your midpoint rule function to run for a couple test functions, you can also hard-code them in by saying "y=sin(x)" etc instead of "y=f(ci)".  But then you would have to change your code every time you have a new function to integrate!

Comment: Last argument to `linspace` should be `N`, not `N-1`